# When I run JavaFx class on my Mac, no window appears but a java icon appears in my dock

Tags: java, javafx

Can someone help please, when I run a JavaFx class on my Mac, no window appears but a java icon appears in my dock. When I click to show this file in finder, I see a file called java- Unix executable. I have no idea what is wrong, I have tried so many tutorials.

I am running this program on eclipse with jdk 12 and JavaFx13.

This is my code:

```
package JavaFx;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class JavaFx extends Application {
    Button button;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage lol) throws Exception {
        lol.setTitle("Title");
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click me");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        lol.setScene(scene);
        lol.show();     
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your IDE, Java version/vendor, JavaFX version, and how do you run your project (from IDE or with Maven or Gradle), including the VM options (if JavaFX 11+).

Comment: Switch sdk to 8, 10 or 13 if you‘re using 11 and javafx

Comment: Hi, I just updated the post to include what you have said.